# PHP/MYSQL while loop only displays the last record

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
include('config.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $name_system = $row['name'];
    $value_system = $row['value'];

    if($name_system=='website_register' AND $value_system==1)
        {$register_system = 1;}
    else
        {$register_system = 0;}

    if($name_system=='website_offline' AND $value_system==1)
        {$offline_system = 1;}
    else
        {$offline_system = 0;}
}
```

My problem is the fact that the loop only displays the last record from "system" table.

Comment: Where and how are you displaying it? That's not in the code you posted.

Comment: there is no where in your code you are outputting anything

Comment: Your code just sets a few variables over and over again. So after the loop the last iteration determines the values of those variables. I can't see any output or displaying, however.

Comment: You're over-writing all your variables on each loop, so only the last set is there when you finish.

Comment: could you write an example of the database entries? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is the fact that the loop only it displays the last record from

No, the problem is the fact that the loop displays *nothing*. The display happens afterward, in code that's outside the loop and therefore gets executed only once, when the cursor has browsed the whole table and only the last row remains in `$row` to be printed.

Move the code that does the `echo` or `print` or whatever *inside* the loop, and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

This is sloppy, but it will show you what's happening as it goes through the loop:

```
include('config.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name_system = $row['name'];
    $value_system = $row['value'];

    if($name_system=='website_register' AND $value_system==1)
    {$register_system = 1;}
    else
    {$register_system = 0;}

    if($name_system=='website_offline' AND $value_system==1)
    {$offline_system = 1;}
    else
    {$offline_system = 0;}

    print "$name_system, $value_system, $register_system, $offline_system<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're overriding the last value each time on the same variable. Instead, add it as a new cell in an array. e.g. each place instead of doing

```
$register_system = 1;
```

Do

```
$register_system[] = 1;
```

At the end your can do `print_r($register_system)` to see all the value. You'll notice the keys of the array are 0,1,... You can consider using the `$row['name']` as the key, like this:

```
$register_system[$row['name']] = 1
```

Assuming of-course these are distinct values.

Comment: I want to define $register_system and $offline_system variables and then use them in other files for comparisons and other actions.

Comment: You can do that (just use `global`). Although I would recommend using classes and making $register_system and offline_system arrays which belong to this class, that was instanced from your other file.

Comment: That's a different question. If you've managed to overcome this question, close it and open another with your direct question and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

the `echo/print` needs to be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use break wherever it is necessary...

Use the logic of flag variable...

Comment: What do you mean? I don't quite understand where you are going with your answer.

Comment: if($row['name']=='website_register' AND $row['value']==1)
        {$register_system[] = 1;}.....when this condition bcomes true....he should use break to come out of the loop...

Comment: So, not really an answer to the question posed, just a suggestion for better program flow?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to store your items into an array.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $name_system[] = $row['name'];
    $value_system[] = $row['value'];

    if($row['name']=='website_register' AND $row['value']==1)
        {$register_system[] = 1;}
    else
        {$register_system[] = 0;}

    if($row['name']=='website_offline' AND $row['value']==1)
        {$offline_systemp[] = 1;}
    else
        {$offline_system[] = 0;}
}
```

That way you can print out each of the values by doing something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_system); $i++) {
    echo 'Name system is: '.$name_system[$i];
}
```